# Codeigniter - foreach condition insert to db

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, codeigniter, foreach

I have these codes that insert arrays to db if all the arrays have values. The problem is that, if one or more of the arrays have no value, it still insert to db but has null values of course. Can someone please help me on how to make a condition that all the `samp_id` that HAVE VALUES only are the ones will only be inserted to db, so that I don't have null value rows. Thanks in advance.

This is my CONTROLLER:

```
    public function save_section_test1() {
  //echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);die;
    $samp = $this->input->post('samp');
    $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
    $specify = $this->input->post('specify');

    $save_sect = array(
        array(
            'emp_id' => $this->input->post('emp_id'),
            'section_id' => $this->input->post('section'),
            'test_id' => $this->input->post('drop_molec'),
            'samp_id' => $samp[0],
            'quantity' => $quantity[0],
            'specification' => $specify[0],
        ),
        array(
            'emp_id' => $this->input->post('emp_id'),
            'section_id' => $this->input->post('section'),
            'test_id' => $this->input->post('drop_molec'),
            'samp_id' => $samp[1],
            'quantity' => $quantity[1],
            'specification' => $specify[1],
        ),
        array(
            'emp_id' => $this->input->post('emp_id'),
            'section_id' => $this->input->post('section'),
            'test_id' => $this->input->post('drop_molec'),
            'samp_id' => $samp[2],
            'quantity' => $quantity[2],
            'specification' => $specify[2],
        ),
    );
    foreach ($save_sect as $save){     
        $this->db->insert('tblsavesection', $save);   
    }
    redirect(base_url('user/show'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `foreach` when you have [`insert_batch()`](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#insert)

To remove sub array which does not have value for key`sampl_id`, you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php),

For example :

```
$data = array_filter($array,function($item) {return !empty($item['sampl_id']);});

// then insert
if(!empty($data)){  
   $this->db->insert_batch('your_table', $data);
}else{
   echo 'seems not even single item has valid sampl_id';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update. I can now insert to db depending the number of arrays. The problem now is that I get error message that says all the arrays that have no values are "Undefined offset". But the insert to db function works fine.

Update to my foreach
    foreach ($save_sect as $save) {

```
        if (!empty($save['samp_id'])){
            $this->db->insert('tblsavesection', $save);
        }
    }
```